# Template variables doesn't updates after redirect in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am building simple django app where I want to do some parsing when user click button on the frontend.

I have template variable {{ parsing }} which I am using inside index.html to disable button for parsing when user click on it

```
<div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Parsing group">
  <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" id="parseButton" {% if parsing %} disabled {% endif %}>
    <i class="fa fa-terminal gradient-text"></i>
      <span class="gradient-text">| Parse</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Next what I do is JQuery method which sends ajax request to my backend to initialize variables for parsing and method from views.py returns redirect to the same page (index.html).

```
    $('#parseButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'initialize_parsing/',
            headers: {"X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken")},
            data: {}
        });
```

Then my views.py:

```
def initialize_before_parsing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frontendTracker = FrontendTracker()
        frontendTracker.progress = 0
        frontendTracker.parsing = True

    return redirect("index")


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        frontendTracker = FrontendTracker()
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["showAnnotation"] = frontendTracker.showAnnotationButton
        context["parsing"] = frontendTracker.parsing
        context["progress"] = frontendTracker.progress

        return context
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("initialize_parsing/", initialize_before_parsing, name="initialize_before_parsing"),
]
```

Finally what is bother me is that when I send that ajax request and everything works fine when my page being redirected {{progres}} template variable isn't changed or any other until I do refresh.
Doing refresh with js when ajax is success isn't something which I want to do because I have some other methods inside js which I want to execute after that ajax request and that will reset my js code.
How can achieve to change value of parsing variable without refresh?

Comment: to add to @Tim's answer: you could work with a JSOn response on async ajax request to use that data in the ajax response function to update your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have state in 2 places:  in the browser and on the server.

When you load a page from the server then it parses the state on the server and fills in the template accordingly.  When you make the AJAX call you pass state to the server, but don't do anything to the state of the page in the browser.  On a subsequent reload you see the reflected change in the browser because you passed that state through the template again.

I don't know too much about `FrontendTracker` or your specific problem, so I don't know what the best solution is.  One solution is add a `.done(function( data ) { /* your code */ })` handler to the `$.ajax` call and then manipulate the content of the page to reflect how you want the page to change.  However, it seems like you have some sort of `progress` value, so you likely need to make subsequent AJAX calls to get updates from the server for updated values of that.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, basically `FrontendTracker` is singleton which is there to change these values from multiple places.
Yes you are right I want to track progress of some parsing and I already know solution for manipulating page from js but I wanted to use these template variables instead of doing everything in js.

Comment: @Luka It's possible to make a Django view that replies with just the parsed template snippet and then you insert that into the page where you want it.

Comment: I am not sure what is that exactly I started using django few days ago,  but at the end I managed to resolve problem with js like you told me. I just wanted to be sure that there is no way to solve that using pure template variables. If you have some doc for _Django view that replies with just the parsed template snippet_ be free to send me I would like to check. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: A Django view can respond with any HTTP response.  Normally an AJAX request returns a `JsonResponse`, yours responds with a `redirect`, but you could also have it respond with `render(request, 'index.html', context)` and then your JS would have HTML in the `data`.  You could then use `$("#parsethingy").html(data)` to replace that part of the page with the HTML.